# Doesn't change state POST in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

"I'm puzzled why post.title and post.body aren't updating as expected. I attempted to manage separate state variables for title and body, but the issue persisted."

**CreatePost.jsx**

```
export default function CreatePost() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({ title: "", body: "" });

    function addNewPost(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newPost = {
            ...post,
            id: Date.now(),
        };
        console.log(newPost);
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <MyInput
                placeholder="Enter title"
                onChange={(e) => setPost({ ...post, title: e.target.value })}
                value={post.title}
                type="text"
            />
            <MyInput
                placeholder="Enter description"
                value={post.body}
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) =>
                    setPost({
                        ...post,
                        body: e.target.value,
                    })
                }
            />
            <MyButton onClick={addNewPost}>Create post</MyButton>
        </form>
    );
}

I rewatched my code hundrend times and I don't know why it doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `MyInput` component is not handling the `onChange` event correctly. In your `CreatePost` component, you are passing the `onChange` function to `MyInput` like this:

```
<MyInput
    placeholder="Enter title"
    onChange={(e) => setPost({ ...post, title: e.target.value })}
    value={post.title}
    type="text"
/>
```

And similarly for the body input. However, in your `MyInput.jsx`, you are trying to spread `props`, which doesn't include the `onChange` and `value` properties directly. You need to modify your `MyInput.jsx` component to handle `onChange` and `value` correctly. Here's how you can do it:

```
export default function MyInput({ placeholder, onChange, value, type }) {
    return (
        <input
            className={classes.MyInput}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            type={type}
        />
    );
}
```

Now, your `MyInput` component should correctly handle the `onChange` and `value` properties, and your `CreatePost` component should work as expected. Make sure to update the import statements in `CreatePost.jsx` to match the new structure of the `MyInput` component.

Comment: Thanky very much, it helped